# Go build "with no buildable Go source files in" error

Tags: go

I tried to go build a project, however, it always encounter the following error.

Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/gocql/gocql/helpers.go:14:2: no buildable Go source files in /home/beego/src/mixpanel/releases/20160304055749/Godeps/_workspace/src/gopkg.in/inf.v0

both gocql and inf.v0 are packages that I installed.

I am confused and I cannot find a solution. Please share some hints on it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1st, make sure you `sourced` your `setup`. Next, to build something make sure they are `package main`. If that doesn't work, `go get` and try again